# How to model arbitrarily nested categories and subcategories?

Tags: python, django

I am looking for an efficient way to model product categories and arbitrarily many nested subcategories in Django for eCommerce purposes. What I currently have now works but it becomes a problem when you want to do a query to get all, say, books because you need to first look up all the subcategories of 'Book' recursively, and then get all books from those subcategories.

Let's say you have a primary school math textbook, it would belong to:

Books -> Textbooks -> Primary school

...and to get all the books one would have to do a monster query like this:

```
>>> from products.models import Product, Category
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> c = Category(name='Books')
>>> c.save()
>>> c1 = Category(name='Textbooks', parent=c)
>>> c1.save()
>>> c2 = Category(name='Primary school', parent=c1)
>>> c2.save()
>>> p = Product(title='Math textbook', description='Math textbook for 4th grade', price=20, category=c2)
>>> p.save()
>>> Product.objects.filter(Q(category__name='Books') | Q(category__parent__name='Books') | Q(category__parent__parent__name='Books'))
<QuerySet [<Product: Product object (3)>]>
```

...which is inefficient and you can't know in advance how nested the categories would be.

Here is how simplified models look like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be to add another field to the category model which has the hierarchical name of the category like Books.Textbooks.Primary_school and then search using a query like `Product.objects.filter(category__full_name__icontains='Books')`. You can automate the population of the full_name field by overriding the save function.
Thus, the category class becomes

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    full_name = models.TextField() # Can also set this to be CharField and choose max_length according to level of hierarchy expected.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.full_name = self.parent.full_name + '.' + self.name  # Not a top level category
        else:
            self.full_name = self.name  # in case of a top level category
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```